# Connecting to mlab

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mlab

I am trying to connect to my database in mLab. I created an account of course, and a DB then added a user (crud). Then I tried connecting through mongo shell using this command:

```
$ mongo ds046027.mlab.com:46027/crud -u crud -p 123456
```

always end up facing this error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.0
connecting to: mongodb://ds046027.mlab.com:46027/crud
2017-12-21T19:13:58.264+0300 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 
52.178.209.192:46027 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2017-12-21T19:13:58.265+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to 
server ds046027.mlab.com:46027, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I also tried using the string uri:

```
mongodb://crud:123456@ds046027.mlab.com:46027/crud
```

and this error comes up in my VS Code:

```
failed to connect to server [ds046027.mlab.com:46027] on first connect 
[MongoError: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.178.209.192:46027]
```

Note: connecting to the default localhost:27017 through mongod works just fine and I can access the database and do anything with it.

I have mongo 3.6.0 and I know it has some problems if that's one of them. how can I fix it?

**UPDATE:**
These are all the steps I'm following, tell me if I'm missing something,

- Installed mongo 3.6.0 on windows 10
- Created a DB file inside the data file (it works with the local mongod)
- Created an Account: { user: "yousefGh", account: "yousefGh" }
- created a DB: crud
- added a user: crud, and this is its config at mLab:
    {
    "_id": "crud.crud",
    "user": "crud",
    "db": "crud",
    "roles": [
        {
            "role": "dbOwner",
            "db": "crud"
        }
     ]
     }
- `cmd: mongo ds046027.mlab.com:46027/crud -u crud -p 123456`

hope you can find anything!!

Comment: Is there a firewall between you and mlab perhaps? Your syntax is correct. You could try making a supersmall app that connects to the DB and upload it to Heroku or AWS. Then see if it's able to connect or not. If it can, then the problem is with your connection or computer.

Comment: @MikaS I'll do it. But before, look at my Update if I'm missing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was connected to my university's wifi and it turns out that it is the problem!